# Couldn't retrieve data from my database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

[I have a problem in my system. Last time i checked, my system was working fine but now i get this error and it seems like my system cannot retrieve data from my database. I am getting a Token mismatch exception even though i have csrf token in all of my forms. Somebody Help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPtRj.png)

Answer (score 1):

1- You might missed the crsf token in your form please check it if missed
add this to your form `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`
2- If you have it already you should clear your laravel cache and view cache.
 - php artisan clear:cache
 - php artisan view:clear
3- One more think please screenshot your error too it is easy to look at.

Comment: how can i clear the cache if its already live in the net? is there like a cmd in the cpanel to do the command? you can see the screenshot by clicking my main question. tnx

Answer (score 0):

A Token Mismatch Exception can occur from other situations other than a form missing a csrf token. An expired session or expired token on an old page can also cause the problem. Try logging out and back in, and try clearing your cookies on your site to see if it's a problem with your session.

Could you also provide a snippet of the code in question? What does your csrf token code look like? It's possible that it's just not a proper use of the csrf token.

Comment: i have this code in all of my forms {{ csrf_field() }}. my login is not working as well.

Comment: When you inspect the HTML, do you see the hidden input with a randomized token in it? It's possible that malformed HTML is also pushing the csrf input out of the form if the form's HTML is broken. Can you copy and paste the form code in its entirety?

Comment: It's possible that there's something wrong with the routes or middleware. Are you using the built-in authentication scaffolding generated by "artisan make:auth" or are you trying to roll-your-own auth system?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="56u9GDO4A4IVfVT9TJ26cQ61tIIfCb5PVvBzyvKU"> this is what i see when do the inspect element. by the way, my application is hosted in the net

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to resolve this issue that are following:-

```
1) Add CSRF token in form i.e. like 2 other answer suggest you
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
 if you still get the error of Csrf token then you have one more solution

2) Open app/http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
   protected $except = [
    //
    '/login',
   ];
 Add your route here suppose you  have one login route you can define here and remove csrf_field() or
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">  
 from your login form
```

Try to resolve with first method if not works go for 2nd one. Hope it helps!